# Java applet and Database connection

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, applet

I'm a building a web application in java. I have to create an applet for displaying some charts to the clients. The problem is that I don't want the applet to connect directly to the database for security reasons.

Which is the best way to get the data without connection to the database? I was thinking of creating a servlet which sends the `ResultSet` or a list of Strings to the applet with URLConnection. But I'm not sure this is the correct way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, providing a servlet that returns the results in JSON or XML format is the most sensible approach.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do that. If Java Applet is the solution for you I think you should make a Apache Commons `HTTPClient` and request a Servlet running on your server. The servlet make the communication with the DB and return the data in either XML or JSON which is you can parse on the Applet.

There are other ways to do that as well. You can make Web-Services for that which serves the same purpose. If I would be on your place I will put my money on RESTFul Service. :)